Lucid multisig transaction
I'm working on a project that requires 2 wallets to sign a transaction.
The backend, written in java, produces a hex encoded version of the TX that is correctly processed by Eternl. Once imported the tx in Eternl, I can just sign and submit it and everything works like a charm.
I am now trying to integrated the frontend by fetching the pre-half-signed-transaction from the backend, import into lucid, and sign via eternl.
What I'm strugging with is loading the TX in lucid.
What I'm doing is:

  const sign = async () => {

    const lucid = await Lucid.new(
      new Blockfrost(getBlockfrostUrl(network), getBlockfrostKey(network)),
      "Mainnet",
    );

    lucid.selectWallet(walletHandle)

    const tx = lucid.fromTx(txHexBytes)
    const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete()
    signedTx.submit()
  }

But I get the following error:
lucid.js:274 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: api.signTx is not a function
    at Object.signTx (lucid.js:274:46)
    at eval (tx_complete.js:70:55)
    at TxComplete.complete (tx_complete.js:110:19)
    at sign (whatever.tsx:167:38)
    ```


Any ideas?

Alternatively, can you point to a lucid multisig example?

Thanks


It appears thatwalletHandle is not what lucid expects
From the docs it appears that it wants the already "resolved" wallet API
On a side note, lucid is no longer maintained
To avoid other surprises either switch to one of the forks or try out plu-ts-offchain

Thanks Michele! walletHandle was indeed one of the issues. Once that one was fixed, it was easier to implement the multisig as expected.
I will also look at lucid alternatives, but my shitty website had already it integrated and was looking for a quick win. As soon as I have a moment will check plu-ts!
Thank you

Right,
eventually found the issue(s),
in this line
lucid.selectWallet(walletHandle)
the walletHandle was not correctly setup, and lead to the TypeError: api.signTx is not a function
More over, in case of multisig instead of sign the partialSign must be used instead.
The new code looks something like:
lucid.selectWallet(walletHandle)
const witness = await lucid.fromTx(txBytes).partialSign()
const txSigned = await ucid.fromTx(txBytes).assemble([witness]).complete()txSigned.submit()

Thanks to all the people that helped!

try
const tx = lucid.newTx(txHexBytes).complete()
const txSigned = await tx.sign().complete();
